# CakePHP 3 query builder with two like values

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

How can I modify my CakePHP 3 query builder so that it could have two "like" functions with values (of "OR" logic function)?

This works:

```
$exp->eq('b2','my_value')->like('b3','%'.$value.'%')
```

I would like something like this (it does not work):

```
$exp->eq('b2','my_value')->like('b3','%'.$valueB3.'%')->like('b4','%'.$valueB4.'%')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless stated otherwise, the expression builder will combine statements via `AND`. If you want to use `OR` with the expression builder, use the `or_()` method, and pass the resulting new expression object to wherever you need it, like for example:

```
$exp
    ->eq('b2', 'my_value')
    ->add($exp->or_(
        function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $or) use ($valueB3, $valueB4) {
            return $or
                ->like('b3', '%' . $valueB3 . '%')
                ->like('b4', '%' . $valueB4 . '%');
        }
    ));
```

That would produce:

```sql
b2 = 'my_value' AND (b3 LIKE '%valueB3%' OR b4 LIKE '%valueB4%')
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**